# HTML CSS Alignment in class skills_group

Tags: html, css

Need help aligning those sections:

```css
/*=============== SKILLS ===============*/

.skills__content{
  row-gap: 3.5rem;
}

.skills__title{
  font-size: var(--h3-font-size);
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.skills__box{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  column-gap: 3rem
}

.skills__group {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  align-content: flex-start;
  row-gap: 1rem;
}


.skills__data{
  display: flex;
  column-gap: .5rem;
}

.skills__data i{
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.skills__name{
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: .5rem;
}

.skills__level{
  font-size: var(--smaller-font-size);
}
```

```html
<!-- skills -->
      <div class="skills__content grid" data-content id="skills">

          <div class="skills_area">
              <h3 class="skills_title">
                  Desenvolvedor Frontend
              </h3>

              <div class="skills__box">
                  <div class="skills__group">
                      <div class="skills__data">
                          <i class="uil uil-check"></i>

                          <div>
                              <h3 class="skills__name">HTML</h3>
                              <span class="skills__level">Intermediário</span>
                          </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="skills__data">
                          <i class="uil uil-check"></i>

                          <div>
                              <h3 class="skills__name">JavaScript</h3>
                              <span class="skills__level">Avançado</span>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="skills__group">

                          <div class="skills__data">
                              <i class="uil uil-check"></i>

                              <div>
                                  <h3 class="skills__name">Bootstrap</h3>
                                  <span class="skills__level">Avançado</span>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="skills__data">
                          <i class="uil uil-check"></i>

                          <div>
                              <h3 class="skills__name">CSS</h3>
                              <span class="skills__level">Intermediário</span>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="skills_area">
              <h3 class="skills_title">
                  Desenvolvedor Mobile
              </h3>

              <div class="skills__box">
                  <div class="skills__group">
                      <div class="skills__data">
                          <i class="uil uil-check"></i>

                          <div>
                              <h3 class="skills__name">Swift</h3>
                              <span class="skills__level">Avançado</span>
                          </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="skills__data">
                          <i class="uil uil-check"></i>

                          <div>
                              <h3 class="skills__name">Storyboard</h3>
                              <span class="skills__level">Avançado</span>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="skills__group">

                          <div class="skills__data">
                              <i class="uil uil-check"></i>

                              <div>
                                  <h3 class="skills__name">SwiftUI</h3>
                                  <span class="skills__level">Intermediário</span>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="skills__data">
                          <i class="uil uil-check"></i>

                          <div>
                              <h3 class="skills__name">Kotlin</h3>
                              <span class="skills__level">Intermediário</span>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="skills_area">
              <h3 class="skills_title">
                  Extras
              </h3>

              <div class="skills__box">
                  <div class="skills__group">
                      <div class="skills__data">
                          <i class="uil uil-check"></i>

                          <div>
                              <h3 class="skills__name">Inglês</h3>
                              <span class="skills__level">Avançado</span>
                          </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="skills__data">
                          <i class="uil uil-check"></i>

                          <div>
                              <h3 class="skills__name">MySQL</h3>
                              <span class="skills__level">Avançado</span>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="skills__group">

                          <div class="skills__data">
                              <i class="uil uil-check"></i>

                              <div>
                                  <h3 class="skills__name">Python</h3>
                                  <span class="skills__level">Avançado</span>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="skills__data">
                          <i class="uil uil-check"></i>

                          <div>
                              <h3 class="skills__name">Design Thinking</h3>
                              <span class="skills__level">Intermediário</span>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

So far it looks like this, I've tried everything but it seems like its dependent on the text length from the skills_data and skills_name. whenever i change it i change the formatting on the website, so it looks terrible. I've spend a lot of time trying to make it 2 columns of 2 names, and when i could do it this second bug happened.

Comment: There seems to at least be a couple of things. 1. I count 37 opening `<div` tags and 38 closing `</div` tags. Mismatched tags can make the site look bad as well, for the browser has to "guess" as to how to handle what you _meant_ to do for the layout, and might not render as expected. 2. All of your CSS classes have double underscores `__` between the names, but yet there are some places that only a single underscore is used between the name? I'd say correct those things first, and then see where you stand.

Comment: Thank you! The problem was with the double underscores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edited the class ".skills__group", added "width: 55%;" to standardize the width of the items and edited the ".skills__box" class, added "margin-left: 20%;" and edited "justify-content: left;"

```css
/*=============== SKILLS ===============*/

.skills__content{
  row-gap: 3.5rem;
}

.skills__title{
  font-size: var(--h3-font-size);
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.skills__box{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  column-gap: 3rem;
  margin-left: 20%;
}

.skills__group {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  align-content: flex-start;
  row-gap: 1rem;
  width: 55%;
}


.skills__data{
  display: flex;
  column-gap: .5rem;
}

.skills__data i{
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.skills__name{
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: .5rem;
}

.skills__level{
  font-size: var(--smaller-font-size);
}
```

```html
<!-- skills -->
      <div class="skills__content grid" data-content id="skills">

          <div class="skills_area">
              <h3 class="skills_title">
                  Desenvolvedor Frontend
              </h3>

              <div class="skills__box">
                  <div class="skills__group">
                      <div class="skills__data">
                          <i class="uil uil-check"></i>

                          <div>
                              <h3 class="skills__name">HTML</h3>
                              <span class="skills__level">Intermediário</span>
                          </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="skills__data">
                          <i class="uil uil-check"></i>

                          <div>
                              <h3 class="skills__name">JavaScript</h3>
                              <span class="skills__level">Avançado</span>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="skills__group">

                          <div class="skills__data">
                              <i class="uil uil-check"></i>

                              <div>
                                  <h3 class="skills__name">Bootstrap</h3>
                                  <span class="skills__level">Avançado</span>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="skills__data">
                          <i class="uil uil-check"></i>

                          <div>
                              <h3 class="skills__name">CSS</h3>
                              <span class="skills__level">Intermediário</span>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="skills_area">
              <h3 class="skills_title">
                  Desenvolvedor Mobile
              </h3>

              <div class="skills__box">
                  <div class="skills__group">
                      <div class="skills__data">
                          <i class="uil uil-check"></i>

                          <div>
                              <h3 class="skills__name">Swift</h3>
                              <span class="skills__level">Avançado</span>
                          </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="skills__data">
                          <i class="uil uil-check"></i>

                          <div>
                              <h3 class="skills__name">Storyboard</h3>
                              <span class="skills__level">Avançado</span>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="skills__group">

                          <div class="skills__data">
                              <i class="uil uil-check"></i>

                              <div>
                                  <h3 class="skills__name">SwiftUI</h3>
                                  <span class="skills__level">Intermediário</span>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="skills__data">
                          <i class="uil uil-check"></i>

                          <div>
                              <h3 class="skills__name">Kotlin</h3>
                              <span class="skills__level">Intermediário</span>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="skills_area">
              <h3 class="skills_title">
                  Extras
              </h3>

              <div class="skills__box">
                  <div class="skills__group">
                      <div class="skills__data">
                          <i class="uil uil-check"></i>

                          <div>
                              <h3 class="skills__name">Inglês</h3>
                              <span class="skills__level">Avançado</span>
                          </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="skills__data">
                          <i class="uil uil-check"></i>

                          <div>
                              <h3 class="skills__name">MySQL</h3>
                              <span class="skills__level">Avançado</span>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="skills__group">

                          <div class="skills__data">
                              <i class="uil uil-check"></i>

                              <div>
                                  <h3 class="skills__name">Python</h3>
                                  <span class="skills__level">Avançado</span>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="skills__data">
                          <i class="uil uil-check"></i>

                          <div>
                              <h3 class="skills__name">Design Thinking</h3>
                              <span class="skills__level">Intermediário</span>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```